# How to move element center from both horizontal and vertical using transform:translate

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to move my division center from both horizontal and vertical but it is not working. Here is my code

```
<body>
    <div class="main"></div>
</body>
```

and css code

```
.main{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    transform: translate(50% ,50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

while using `transform: translate();` you should use `position: absolute;` to the element.

```
position: absolute
right: 50%;
bottom: 50%;
transform: translate(50%,50%);
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/venumadhavdiv/pen/ORKWMx?editors=1100/)

Answer (score 1):

By default, every element is static which means you cannot move them. So add this to your rule.

```
position: relative;
```

So you can move it

Click [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) to learn more about `position`

Answer (score 0):

I believe to accomplish that trick you'll need absolute positioning and a top/left value of 50%.

```css
.main{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%; 
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="main"></div>
</body>
```